# JLabel not aligning to the right in a BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have some `JLabel` components in a `JPanel` (`taskPanel`) with a `BoxLayout` (which is in a panel with a `GridBagLayout`) and the labels are refusing to be aligned to the right. They keep aligning to the left no matter how I manipulate them.

Here I setup the `GridBagConstraints` for the panel that has the labels

```
GridBagConstraints taskPanelC = new GridBagConstraints();
taskPanelC.gridx = 4;
taskPanelC.gridy = 0;
taskPanelC.gridwidth = 1;
taskPanelC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
taskPanelC.weighty = 1;
taskPanelC.weightx = 1;
taskPanelC.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
timePanel.add(taskPanel, taskPanelC);
```

Here are the `GridBagConstraints` for the panel before the task panel

```
//Setup the gridBagLayout
GridBagConstraints timeTextC = new GridBagConstraints();
timeTextC.gridx = 1;
timeTextC.gridy = 0;
timeTextC.gridwidth = 3;
timeTextC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
timeTextC.weighty = 1;
timeTextC.weightx = 1;
```

Here I add a header to the `taskPanel` (I don't really care how this is aligned)

```
taskListLabel = new JLabel("Task List");
taskListLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
taskPanel.add(taskListLabel);
```

Here is where I am adding the labels I want to be right-justified/aligned. I have tried `setHorizontalTextPosition` and `setAlignmentX` and both do not work, causing the text to stay left aligned. However, when I tried `setAlignmentX`, the header became unaligned with the task labels

```
JLabel task = new JLabel(name, SwingConstants.RIGHT);
//Allow deleting of the label
task.addMouseListener(new ClickListener());
//Add task to the task panel
taskPanel.add(task);
```

This is what it currently looks like [image: img]

I want the text under task list to be right-aligned so the time is always on the right

Here is a link to the full code in case the summary was not enough: [Github Repo](https://github.com/kftang/WorkflowTimer/blob/master/src/WorkflowTimer.java)

Comment: We don't want code snippets nor the full code. Rather you will want to create and post a valid [mcve]. Please have a look at [help] as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections for more information on how to improve your question and increase your chances of getting decent help.

Comment: `taskListLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));` Not on this Windows box. The default undecorated (sans serif) font is Arial, and Helvetica is simply not available. Better to use the constant for an undecorated font, namely `Font.SANS_SERIF`. That will use Helvetica on OS X, Arial on Windows, and whatever is the default undecorated font on *nix systems.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you, I wanted to use a constant but could not find one

Comment: Tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the following methods from the JLabel API:

1. `setHorizontalAlignment(...)` - used to align the text when the width of the label is greater than the width of the text
2. `setAlignmentX(...)` - might be used by the layout manager to align component

Comment: I've tried
     setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT) 
and it did not work as expected, I added a picture to show what was going on

Comment: @Kennyftang a picture doesn't help. The problem is with your code and the way you use the layout managers. Your were asked in the first comment to your question to post an `MCVE`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood a bit. I have changed the layout and now the whole thing is under 1 gridbaglayout. As it turns out, I had to set both the header and the individual labels using setAlignmentX and it finally worked. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I copied the entire code from the link

https://github.com/kennyftang/WorkflowTimer/blob/master/src/WorkflowTimer.java

I guess the code is incomplete, as addTask(String name) method is not called anywhere in the code.
I am really confused about which label you want to be on the right side? As I observed that the "task list" are already on the right side.
Please provide the image explaining which label you want on which side? Also, don't use so many layouts and get confused for this small UI just one layout is enough.

Step 1 Comment the following line.

```
// taskPanel.add(taskListLabel);
```

Step2 Add the following 4 lines in that place,

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(taskListLabel, BorderLayout.EAST);
taskPanel.add(panel,BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

Step3 Comment the following line.

```
//taskPanel.add(task);
```

Step4 Add the following 4 lines in that place,

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(task,BorderLayout.EAST);
taskPanel.add(panel,BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

Let me know if you have any issues. Thanks.
I know this is bit heavy solution, here instead of Jpanel we may use some even light weight component as well.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I have added a picture for explanation